# Vertically aligning a text element inside a parent div element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a text inside a `div`. I have read 4 topics here on SoF and all of them recommend to use the `vertical-align` property. In my case it doesn't work.

```css
.free {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4;
  -moz-border-radius: 4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #ff0000;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: dashed #ff0000 2px;
  width: 105px;
  height: 46px;
  font-size: 1.07rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.free p {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="free">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c95rww13/)**

ADD the following code in your css

```
.free {
line-height:46px;   
}

.free p {       
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:0; margin:0;
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `display: inline-block;` instead of it use `display: table;`. Check following:

```css
.free {
  display: table;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4;
  -moz-border-radius: 4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #ff0000;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: dashed #ff0000 2px;
  width: 105px;
  height: 46px;
  font-size: 1.07rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.free p {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="free">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```